# Inserting same records again and again in the same table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with 1000 records, I want to insert the same number of records again so that the total record count will be 2000. Is there a way I can Insert same records into the same table again and again:

For example:

```
SELECT * from MyTable ;   has 1000 records
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO Mytable  ( All the records from above table) ;
```

Please advise. Thanks !!

Comment: Please show the layout of the table.  In some cases, this is possible.  In other cases, it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, [*`INSERT INTO .... SELECT`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) syntax. And you can also `LIMIT` the number of records to be copied.

```
INSERT INTO Mytable  SELECT * from Mytable LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

But this would fail, if you have a unique data field in the table and you are trying to copy the same again. You have to be cautious in such cases.

If you can omit auto increment primary column and select specific columns to copy, then you have to include those column names with `insert`.

**Example**:

```
INSERT INTO Mytable ( col2, col3, ... )
    SELECT 
        col2, col3, ... 
    FROM Mytable 
    LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks but because of primary key, it's not allowing me to do so. I am getting `Error Code 1062. Duplicate entry "1" for key 'PRIMARY' `

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in my answer. You have to select specific fields which are not unique. Primary key is unique by default. If it is an auto increment field, just omit that field from selection and execute. I.e. like `insert .... select col2, col3, ...`

Comment: Hmm, even though I am starting from `col2` I keep on getting `Error Code 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: When you are selecting limited number of columns to insert, you have to specify that many relevant column names with insert. Like `insert into mytable( col2, col3, .... ) select col2, col3, ... from mytable ...`.